# Adding groupsField @auth rules to schema.graphql causes errors when trying to update with AWS DataStore

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-datastore

I'm getting the following error when I try to update a "Card" object on my front-end (React with NextJS): `POST https://<myAppId>.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql 401`

The issue arose after I updated my `amplify/backend/api/<myAppName>/schema.graphql` schema with the following:

```
type Card
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, provider: iam }
      { allow: private, provider: userPools, operations: [create] }
      { allow: groups, groupsField: "canRead", operations: [read] }
      { allow: groups, groupsField: "canUpdate", operations: [update] }
    ]
  ) {
  approvedTime: AWSTimestamp
  canRead: [String]
  canUpdate: [String]
  id: ID!
  input: AWSJSON
  name: String
  scheduledTime: AWSTimestamp
  status: Status!
  type: String
}
```

Everything generally works fine. I've tested create, read, and update operations in the AppSync Console, and things similarly work on the front-end for the most part. I've configured Amplify as per the [amplify.aws/lib/datastore docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js/#configure-multiple-authorization-types). The front end can get and render the Card objects.

What I'm finding most confusing is that AWS is allowing me to update the Card object on the AppSync console. It also seems to be allowing me to update the Card.input field on the front end, but not the Card.type field? I update the Card as follows:

```js
 await DataStore.save(
        Card.copyOf(initialCardDetails as Card, (updated) => {
          (updated.approvedTime = undefined),
            (updated.input = JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"})),
            (updated.name = "exampleName"),
            (updated.scheduledTime = null),
            (updated.type = "exampleType");
        })
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised as I was typing out this questions that I was trying to set:

```js
 (updated.approvedTime = undefined),
```

For some reason, trying to set approvedTime as `undefined` throws a 401 error. If I try to set it as `null` I don't get a problem. It's very confusing that I never got this error until I changed my `schema.json`. I never had the error with the same code when I had this set up:

```
@auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, provider: iam }
      { allow: private, provider: userPools }
    ]
```

It seems like this could have saved me a lot of hours if the error gave a better clue than a 401 Unauthorized...